# Ubuntu 20 supports run on external ssd?

Tags: boot, system-installation

my question it's because previously i tried to install windows 10 on external ssd but it doesn't work correctly so, i wonder if ubuntu 20 or linux mint have the same problem. Actualy, i use dual boot with Ubuntu 20 and windows 10, but i have been thinking on use completely Ubuntu 20

Comment: Windows is picky on which drives you can install it on.  Ubuntu will install on almost any drive type.

Comment: Three methods, (with varying difficulty), of installing Ubuntu to external drive can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step